# Python - How to open urls (html files) which are located on an internal network with urlopen?

Tags: python-3.x, urlopen

The addresses I am trying to open look like this:
"//usa-qa/QAEngr/QA_Team_VSripathi/Negar/Help files/broken/header_test/main.htm"

They are located on a company's internal network.

I tried this piece of code:

```
 import urllib  
 import urllib.request as ur  
 address="//usa-qa/QAEngr/QA_Team_VSripathi/Negar/Help files/broken/header_test/main.htm"  
 info=ur.urlopen(address)
```

which results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/naref/Desktop/networktest.py", line 14, in <module>  
    info=ur.urlopen(address)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 160, in urlopen  
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 458, in open  
    req = Request(fullurl, data)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 279, in __init__  
    self._parse()  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 284, in _parse  
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %s" % self.full_url)  
ValueError: unknown url type: //usa-qa/QAEngr/QA_Team_VSripathi/Negar/Help files/broken/header_test/main.htm
```

The same happens when converting the path to url:

```
info=ur.urlopen(ur.pathname2url(address))
```

Then I tried to add an "http:" to the beginning of the address:

```
address="http://usa-qa/QAEngr/QA_Team_VSripathi/Negar/Help files/broken/header_test/main.htm"  
info=ur.urlopen(address)
```

Which results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/naref/Desktop/networktest.py", line 14, in <module>  
    info=ur.urlopen(address)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 160, in urlopen  
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 473, in open  
    response = self._open(req, data)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 491, in _open  
    '_open', req)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 451, in _call_chain  
    result = func(*args)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1272, in http_open  
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)  
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1255, in do_open  
    raise URLError(err)  
urllib.error.URLError:<urlopen error [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

It is interesting that this problem gets solved when I map the network drive on my computer which runs windows 8: (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-shortcut-to-map-network-drive)

Also the file can be opened with the open function instead of the urlopen, however I prefer to use urlopen since for my purpose the address might be a website's url.

Comment: your code does not correspond to the traceback. Try `urllib.parse.urljoin('file:', urllib.request.pathname2url(address))`.

Comment: I also made a small change to the first piece of code that I have. It as showing the address start with http: which was wrong, it starts with //

Comment: J. F. I tried the piece of code you suggested. I get this error:

Comment: .
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 491, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 451, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1378, in file_open
    return self.open_local_file(req)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1418, in open_local_file
    raise URLError(msg)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\QAEngr\\QA_Team_VSripathi\\Negar\\Help files\\broken\\header_test\\main.htm'>

Comment: don't put the relevant info into the comments, [edit] your question instead.

Comment: Yeah I did J. F. I was just informing you about the change in the comments.

Comment: I don't see *"The system cannot find the path specified"* error in the question. Create the minimal code example that shows the issue: `open(address)` should succeed, use [the suggested code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634107/python-how-to-open-urls-html-files-which-are-located-on-an-internal-network#comment45568674_28634107) to get url, print the url, `urllib.request.urlopen(url)` should fail, post the full traceback in the question.